# Is Integration of a function not defined at a discrete point between upper and lower limits defined?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, definition

> 1. $$\int_{π/4}^{3π/4}\tan(x)\,dx=0$$
> 2. $$\int_{-2}^{4}|x|/x\,dx=2$$

But is the answer defined or not mathematically at undergraduate level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is true is that $$\lim_{h\to\frac\pi2-}\int_{\frac\pi4}^h\tan x\,\mathrm{d}x+
\int_h^{\frac{3\pi}4}\tan x\,\mathrm{d}x=0$$
This is called the Cauchy principal value of the integral.

The integral itself, considered as an improper Riemann integral, does not converge.  For the improper Riemann integral to exist, both of the limits above would have to exist separately, which of course, they don't.

Comment: @Jay I don't understand what you mean.  What answers are controversial?  I've written what I mean.  What does the integral in your comment have to do with the question?

Comment: No, they really aren't.  There are some contexts in which integrals are understood to be Cauchy principal values.  I assume that's what Herb means.  Any calculus book should tell you that the improper Riemann integral doesn't exist.  As for whether the Cauchy principal value is intended in the context you found, the integral, you didn't tell us the context, so there's no way to know.

Comment: I am at undergraduate level so what ans. Shall be perfect for me? 1."Not exist" 2."0"

Comment: Does not exist.

Comment: Yes, $2$ is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Integral is being defined as $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0} (\int\limits_{\pi/4} ^{\pi/2-\epsilon}tan(x)dx+\int\limits_{\pi/2+\epsilon}^{3\pi/4}tan(x)dx=0)$

Note that the excluded interval around $\pi/2$ is symmetric.